# Unable to invoke ssh.exe in PowerShell even on providing the full path via UiPath Studio

Tags: powershell, ssh, uipath-studio

The following works on my windows machine using `PowerShell`

```
 ssh username@example.com
```

Now, I am trying to run the same command within `PowerShell` using `UiPath Studio` for RPA but I get the standard invalid command error -

```
Invoke Power Shell: the term 'ssh username@example.com' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...
```

However `ssh.exe` does exist on the machine and I even tried providing the absolute path, same result.

Are there any additional configurations to be done on the UiPath / system end to make ssh executable via UiPath Studio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Invoke-SSH, what I did was to do `Import-Module Posh-SSH`, but that resulted to:

```
Import-Module: Could no load file or assembly 'Renci.Ssh.Net
```

So in UiPath Studio I went to Manage Packages and installed the Nuget package for Renci SSH. Afterwards, the Import worked, and then the Invoke-SSH command worked too.

Got this tip from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2VnY48MJQE&ab_channel=techu